# RecyclerView объясните момент с адаптером

Tags: java, android

У меня есть адаптер (взят с сайта):

```
public class HeroAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList heroDataSet;
    public Context mContext;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textUniverse;
        ImageView imageHero;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super (itemView);
            this.imageHero = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            this.textName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.hero_name);
            this.textUniverse = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.hero_universe);
        }
    }



    public HeroAdapter(Context context, ArrayList heroes){
        this.heroDataSet= heroes;
        mContext=context;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hero_card, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        final TextView textViewName = holder.textName;
        final TextView textViewUniverse = holder.textUniverse;
        ImageView imageViewHero = holder.imageHero;
        textViewName.setText(heroDataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
        textViewUniverse.setText(heroDataSet.get(listPosition).getUniverse());

        String src = heroDataSet.get(listPosition).getImage();
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load("file:///android_asset/images/"+src+".jpg")
                .resize(300, 300)
                .into(imageViewHero);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return heroDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Но он требует импортировать метод `onBindViewHolder`, хотя он и так есть! Если изменить первую строку на: `public class HeroAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeroAdapter.MyViewHolder> {` — все работает. Почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Базовый класс объявлен, как `public static abstract class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder>`, т.е. является обобщенным типом (generic type) и требует параметр-тип (type parameter). Так как вы при наследовании не указали значение параметра `VH`, компилятор подставляет вместо него граничный (bound) тип `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Таким образом, предком вашего класса становится `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` и вам нужно переопределить его абстрактные методы.

Методов, использующих параметр-тип `VH` два:

```
public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position);
```

Заменяя `VH` на `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` получаем требуемые сигнатуры:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
```

Вы реализовали методы:

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)

public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition)
```

В случае с `onCreateViewHolder` использование подтипа `MyViewHolder` в качестве возвращаемого параметра возможно ([JLS 8.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)). Пользователи класса `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` и всех его наследников будут ожидать получить экземпляр `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, и его (точнее его подтип) получат.

Для `onBindViewHolder` напротив, сигнатура вашего метода не эквивалента сигнатуре родительского метода по перегрузке (override-equivalent), т.к. не совпадает с ней ([JLS 8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)). Пользователи класса `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` и всех его наследников захотят передать в метод `RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder`, ваш метод хочет получить на вход `MyViewHolder holder` и может в процессе работы обратиться к полям и методам, существующим только в `MyViewHolder`, что недопустимо.

Поэтому компилятор сообщает о двух ошибках - нереализованном абстрактном методе `onBindViewHolder`, и методе `onBindViewHolder`, отмеченном аннотацией `@Override`, но не переопределяющим метод класса-предка.

Когда вы объявляете свой класс, как `public class HeroAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeroAdapter.MyViewHolder>`, вы подставляете вместо параметра `VH` свой тип `HeroAdapter.MyViewHolder`, предок вашего класса указывается явно, и вы можете использовать вместо обобщенного параметра `VH` свой `MyViewHolder`.